# Sql query to check for name in perticular pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I efficiently find names that don't follow firstname,lastname pattern? I am using my SQL id is the primary key.

```
select name 
    from  Person where name not like '%,%'
```

This include patterns like firstname which is valid. How do I get rid of those results?

Comment: Using `MATCH` would be marginally faster, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name 
from Person 
where instr(name, ',') = 0
```